# URL Redirection without the filename in ColdFusion?

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to achieve 301 redirects such that all of my URLs are redirected to the www version of the given page. Our page structure is: url.com/home/default.cfm. I am trying to rewrite the URLs in ColdFusion to the current directory without the filename.

The code I am using is this:

```
<cfif (CGI.SERVER_NAME NEQ "www.url.com")>
<!-- Save the URL (and $_GET variables too) as the string 'strUrl' -->
<!-- <cfset strUrl = CGI.script_name & "?" & CGI.query_string />-->
<cfset strUrl = CGI.script_name />
<!-- Use 301 for SEO-friendly redirects -->
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved permanently">
<!-- Redirect to new website (this case, added www.) with strUrl added on -->
<cfheader name="Location" value="http://www.url.com#strUrl#">
</cfif>
```

This is so close, except CGI.script_name returns the path WITH the filename. Any ideas how to get just the directory? Keep in mind we may have nested directories, e.g., /foo1/foo2/.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to redirect all traffic going to "domain.com" to "www.domain.com", you may be better off doing it at the webserver level. The webserver will take care of not just CF files, but also static resources like images, css & js files, etc.

Comment: +1 what happens to non CF resources? If available let the webserver handle this stuff.

Comment: Yes, that would've been my preference, but unfortunately our technical setup doesn't allow for this - we're in a large corporation which complicates our server level access. Plus, the primary reason we're doing this is to prevent duplicate indexing of pages in Google (which was a problem before, we'd have the non WWW and the WWW version indexed).

Comment: If you are specifically looking at doing this for Google indexing, you can take a look at Google's "Preferred Domain" instructions for webmasters. See [link]http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=44231

Answer (score 1):

You can use getDirectoryFromPath() to do this, which will also preserve the trailing slash.

```
<cfset strUrl = getDirectoryFromPath(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME)>
```

In addition you simplify the code by using the cflocation tag and specifying the statusCode attribute.

```
<cfif (CGI.SERVER_NAME NEQ "www.url.com")>
<!-- Save the URL (and $_GET variables too) as the string 'strUrl' -->
<!-- <cfset strUrl = CGI.script_name & "?" & CGI.query_string />-->
<cfset strUrl = getDirectoryFromPath(CGI.script_name) />
<!-- Use 301 for SEO-friendly redirects -->
<cflocation url="http://www.url.com#strUrl#" statusCode="301">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<cfset strUrl = listDeleteAt(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME,listLen(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME,'/'),'/') />`

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
<cfset strUrl = Replace(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME, ListLast(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME,'/'), '')>
```

to have the trailing slash as well.